# Не могу достучаться к свойству элемента в JS через id

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Доброе время суток, форумчане.  
Скажите, можно ли в **файле** JavaScript написать таким образом:
Вариант 1

```
$(function () {  
    $("#edit_out3").hidden = true;  
    return false;  
})
```

Обращение по уникальному "id" элемента вместо:

Вариант 2

```
function func3()  
{
    document.forma3.edit_out3.hidden = true;  
    return false;  
}
```

Этим кодом я скрываю элемент `<.input>` в html. Строка в html:

```
<.script type="text/javascript" src="/media/Js/department.js"></script>  
<.input id="edit_out3" type="text" size="40">
```

**Если можно**, то почему у меня вариант 1 **не** работает?

Спасибо

P.S. Просто мне сказали, что запись варианта 2 немного устарела и лучше обращаться по id.
И при работе с фреймверком 'kohana' я встречал файл javascript'a:

```
$(function(){
    $('#multi').MultiFile({
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В варианте 1 вы неправильно меняете атрибут "hidden". Надо так: http://jsfiddle.net/zxbgc8ym/

```
$("#edit_out3").attr('hidden', true);
```

> И при работе с
> фреймверком 'kohana' я встречал файл
> javascript'a
>
> ```
> $(function(){ $('#multi').MultiFile({ ...
> ```

`.MultiFile({ ...` - это дополнительный плагин, который создали вот так:

```
jQuery.fn.MultiFile = function () {
    // this здесь ссылается на jquery-объект, от которого вызван метод
    // в вашем примере с коханой на элемент с идентификатором multi
};
```

P.S. `fn` — это короткая ссылка на jQuery.prototype.

Comment: **Спасибо за разъяснения**.
Только небольшое уточнение:
В файле JS, код:
>$(function () 
>{ 
>    $("#edit_out2").attr('hidden', true);
>    $("#edit_out3").hide();
>    return false;
>})

- будет срабатывать при каждой загрузке страницы.
А если я хочу еще сделать в JS функцию с привязкой к кнопке, я делаю:
>function func1() 
>{ 
>    alert("call func1");
>    $("#edit_out4").attr('hidden', true);
>    return false;
>}
и html:
> <button onclick="func1()">Call func1</button>

Comment: @Konstantin78, и обработчики тоже не рекомендуется оставлять в разметке. Лучше присоединять через код по id: [jquery click](http://jquery-docs.ru/events/click/)

    $("button_id").click(func1);

Comment: Поддерживаю @Alex Krass .

@Konstantin78 - Есть ещё один способ скрытия элемента, добавление класса http://jsfiddle.net/zxbgc8ym/2/

Comment: Итого:

файл JS:

    $(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#knopka1").click(function () {    
    $("#edit_out1").hide();    
    return false;    
    });

файл html:

    <button id="knopka1">hide "input"</button>

Comment: return false в вашем примере не обязательно.

Answer (score 4):

Да, можно. Единственное условие для приведенного кода - наличие подключенной библиотеки jQuery.

```
$(function ()
{
  $("#edit_out3").hide();// это скроет элемент
  //$("#edit_out3").show();// это покажет элемент
  return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Первая явная причина - неправильно оформлено обращение к атрибуту, а вторая - возможно, просто не подключили jquery, потому и не работает присвоение свойству значения. В консоли можно выводить значения для отслеживания этой ситуации.